# How do I make Atom stop adding these new lines

Tags: newline, whitespace, atom-editor

I open in Atom a PHP file I have originally edited in NetBeans IDE.

As soon as I edit a line of code, when checking git versioning view I can see a lot more changes that I have actually done.

All those are new lines added by Atom.

[image: Example php file with new lines added by Atom]

Answer (score 7):

I have solved it by going to Atom Settings, Packages, search for `Whitespace` package and disabled `Remove Trailing Whitespace`.

[image: Whitespace package settings]